# i am trying to use pyautogui image recognition, and im coming out with a exit code of 0, but its not working

Tags: python, image, image-recognition, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time
from time import sleep
import pyscreeze
def openchrome():
    sleep(5)
    chromeIcon = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:\images\PngItem_333605.png')
    print(chromeIcon)
    pyautogui.doubleClick(chromeIcon)
```

Process finished with exit code 0
even the sleep is not working, the bot stops runing after a second or two.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you call the function `openchrome` further in the code?